# svchost consuming more than 50% CPU all the time in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, cpu-usage

I'm using windows 7 ultimate.

svchost containing

1. DCOM Server Process Launcher
2. Plug and Play
3. Power

services is consuming more than 50% of CPU for most of the time. I found this blog post:
http://blog.hansmelis.be/2007/06/17/windows-vista-long-delay-when-switching-songs-in-media-player/

> That process is associated with two
> services: DCOM Server Process Launcher
> and Plug and Play. For the Vulcans
> among us, all logic stops there for a
> second. What do those two services
> have to do with WMP? The answer is
> provided by Vista's new audio engine.
> The new engine supports several audio
> "enhancements". But for the
> enhancements to work, the engine needs
> to determine if your hardware is up to
> the task. And when does it check that?
> Each time a sound output device is
> accessed. That's pretty nice if you
> can do a hot swap of sound hardware,
> but I don't see me doing that anytime
> soon. Anyways, it does provide us with
> the link to the correct service
> because checking hardware is done by
> the "Plug and Play" service.
>
> One might think that deactivating each
> enhancement would solve the problem,
> but that's wishful thinking. The
> configuration of the enhancements is
> located in the properties of the sound
> hardware. When opening the tab, I
> found out that no enhancements were
> active. Hmmm... so why does it check
> the hardware? Well, it does that in
> case you actually enable an
> enhancement. To completely stop the
> hardware checking, you have to tick
> the box labelled **Disable all
> enhancements**. As soon as you do that,
> Vista finally understands you don't
> want to use them

buts thats for vista. Is it the same case with windows 7 too? and I couldn't find any "Disable all enhancements" in my controlpanel>sounds (mmsys.cpl). Where can I find this option in windows 7?

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you scan your computer for malware? I had same issue (different service) and a quick scan with Malwarebytes AntiMalware found and remove some malware causing it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Figure out the Process ID (PID) from the Task Manager.
2. Run this command from a console to find out which services it might be:

   tasklist /svc /fi "PID EQ 1000"
   (where 1000 is the PID)

Or just run [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe), which will drill down into each svchost.

Comment: As mentioned on the other answer, the question already states which services are at fault. This does not help.

Answer (score -1):

svchost basically lies under all system services.  It's rather hard to find out which process is actually running in svchost.  You'll need that info to determine what's running inside.

See [this tutorial](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial129.html)

Comment: He actually said in the question description which services are in the concerned svchost.

Comment: You should also quote the important part since link-only answers are frowned upon. What happens if the site or page goes away? Your answer becomes useless.